# Can I create a CronJob and a Job in the web context?

Tags: ehcache, jobs, sap-commerce-cloud

Normally, we can create CronJobs and Jobs (which extends AbstractJobPerformable) by definining configuration in `*-items.xml` and in `*-spring.xml`. However, I can't get these jobs to access the beans in the web context. Can I create a CronJob and a Job in the web context? If yes, how?

The reason I need the jobs to work in the web context is I need to access the ehcache, and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the job in your web context. Create an own extension for this job and a dependency to your facades extension.

Comment: 1. Will this job still extend `AbstractJobPerformable`? 2. WIll this job be able to access the bean in the web context? I assume I can just do  `(EhCacheCacheManager) Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("wsCacheManager");`

Comment: 1. Yes, you would define the job just like every other job. Only in a new extension. 2. The job will be able to access every bean in the application context. Since the wsCache is defined in the commercewebservices extension you will not be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep using default `cronJobService` to run your jobs then, probably, the only solution would be to 'correctly' get access to a required web context.

Sample groovy script to get access to web application context by its name.

```
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader

final String WEB_CONTEXT_NAME = "/rest"
def contextLoader = ContextLoader.currentContextPerThread.find { it.key.contextName == WEB_CONTEXT_NAME }
assert contextLoader != null

def webApplicationContext = contextLoader.value
webApplicationContext.getBean(EhCacheCacheManager)
```

Keep in mind that `ContextLoader.currentContextPerThread` is a private field. To access the field in java you can use

```
def f = ContextLoader.getDeclaredField("currentContextPerThread");
f.setAccessible(true);
Map<ClassLoader, WebApplicationContext> contexts = f.get(HybrisContextLoaderListener);
```

Sample JobPerformable will be looking like

```
public class WebContextAwareJob extends AbstractJobPerformable<CronJobModel> {

    @Override
    public PerformResult perform(final CronJobModel cronJobModel) {
        final CacheManager cacheManager = getEhCacheManager().getCacheManager();
        final Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("");
    }

    private EhCacheCacheManager getEhCacheManager() {
        return getRegistry().getBean(EhCacheCacheManager.class)
    }

    private WebApplicationContext getRegistry() {
        <see sample code above>
    }
}
```